# How can activate chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener for a specific tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension and I am using Message Passing for this process. The process is this:
1.- popup.js send a request to background when I clicked on an element of popup.

```
function sendMessageToContent(contactName){
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({elementValue: contactName}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

}

2.- background.js listens the request.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.elementValue != null){
        var accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
        var instanceUrl = localStorage.getItem('instanceUrl');       
getContactByName(accessToken,instanceUrl,request.elementValue);
            sendResponse({farewell: "ContactResponse"});
        }
    });
```

and it sends another request to content.js.

```
function getContactByName(accessToken,instanceUrl,contactName){
var urlQuery = 'query';
fetch(instanceUrl+urlQuery,{
    method: 'get',
    headers: new Headers({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+accessToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
})
    .then(response => {
        if(response.status != 200){
               showAuthNotification();
        }
        return response.json()
    })
    .then(data => {
        for(var i = 0; i<data.totalSize; i++){
            contact.push({name:data.records[i].Name, email:data.records[i].Email, id:data.records[i].Id});
        }
        localStorage.setItem('contactInfo', JSON.stringify(contact));
        chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tab) {
                chrome.tabs.update(tab[4].id, {active: true});
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[4].id, {message: "OK"});
        }
                        });

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Request failure: ', error);
    })
```

}

3.- The problem is in this step, after the background's request is sent it should open a specific tab and the listener on the content.js should take the request. this process only works when I am in the current tab, when I active the other tab using `chrome.tabs.update(tab[4].id, {active: true});` the listener

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
console.log(request.message);
```

});

doesn't listen the request.

How could I do that the listener is active for all requests or for a specific tab not just for the current tap?

Comment: Add the relevant code that handles messaging from all three files.

Comment: My question is updated with relevant code, Thank you @PredatorIWD.

Comment: sendMessage doesn't care if the tab is active or not. There's something else wrong in your code. For example, why do you use tab[4]? Also, did you check the background page devtools via chrome://extensions page? Debug the code, set breakpoints, inspect the variables - this is the first step in solving the problem.